# Fix snap application icon on 20.04 [gitkraken]

Tags: launcher, 20.04

After downloading gitkraken from the website (not snap store) the launcher does not show any icon, also he same in the dock.

I searched inside the snap directory `/snap/bin/gitkraken` but couldn't see anything related to a desktop shortcut.

[image: pic]

Any ideas?

Comment: Give the specific link for "downloading gitkraken from the website".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just modified the `.desktop` file to point to the GitKraken icon in the installation folder, which is in the directory:

```
/snap/gitkraken/current/usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken.png
```

The modified `.desktop` file is located at

```
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/gitkraken_gitkraken.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that should be filed to the Snap packager. The installed desktop file points generically to an icon gitkraken. Thus, the application launcher will search in the default icon set for an icon with that name. Such icon does not come with the default Adwaita theme, and likely also not on the Yaru theme, which is Ubuntu's default. Thus, the launcher shows a generic icon. Some alternative icon sets, for example Papirus, contain an icon for it.

*Workaround*

Find an icon and copy it in the folder .local/share/icons.

Comment: Not able to `sudo mv` or using sudo nautilus to move the file there, I get "unable to remove target: Read-only file system". Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to move? Just copy an icon in a folder you own. No sudo needed. If the icon is in a read-only location, you still can copy it. You obviously cannot move it in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install your application via terminal. Delete the application first and then try to reinstall it.

To reinstall (after deleting the current one):

```
sudo snap install gitkraken
```

Comment: still the same.